# ELK stack, index not being created with logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I followed this [link](http://logz.io/blog/install-elk-stack-amazon-aws/) to install ELK stack on AWS EC2 server with Ubuntu 14.04 as AMI.
As the installation link suggests, I created following file:

```
# file_location : /etc/logstash/conf.d/10-syslog.conf

input {
file {
type => "syslog"
path => [ "/var/log/messages", "/var/log/*.log" ]
}
}
output {
stdout {
codec => rubydebug
}
elasticsearch {
host => "localhost" # Use the internal IP of your Elasticsearch server
# for production
}
```

Logstash is supposed to take input from syslog files and output it to elasticsearch. 
But no index is getting created on Elasticsearch server. I am total newbie to ELK stack, any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Whats in /var/log/logstash/logstash.stdout?

Comment: did you try running logstash with --debug flag? and have you made sure your elasticsearch is available to logstash at that IP?

Comment: Change `host => "localhost"` to `hosts => ["localhost"]` (`hosts` in plural form). What happens?

Comment: @SumitKumar I have installed logstash as a service, how to pass arguments to it. For ex : sudo service logstash start . 

 I tried that. Still the same. I think logstash is not even reading the conf file. How to check that ?

Comment: Try to run logstash manually with `/opt/logstash/bin/logstash --debug -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/10-syslog.conf`. What happens?

Comment: @Val I ran the binary from opt folder with passing the conf file location as argument, and it worked. 
But what is the problem when I do start logstash as service.

Comment: @AdarshKumar it is not taking your config file as it is not the default path for it.

Comment: @SumitKumar I checked the default path and its /etc/logstash/conf.d/ in the config file of logstash .

Comment: @AdarshKumar logstash needs a file in -f as config file as by default it won't know which input or output to use. have a look here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/configuration.html#configuration

Comment: -f, --config CONFIGFILE
 Load the Logstash config from a specific file, directory, or a wildcard. If
 given a directory or wildcard, config files will be read from the directory in
 alphabetical order.

Comment: @AdarshKumar can you verify that in your `/etc/init.d/logstash` init script file you have `LS_CONF_DIR=/etc/logstash/conf.d` ? Also what version of Logstash are you running?

Comment: Can you make sure that the user/group running the logstash process has the right to read `/var/log/messages` and `/var/log/*.log`?